# Remove GRUB menu from Windows Disk

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I am currently running two OS's on two physical drives. Windows 7 on an SSD (/dev/sda/) and Ubuntu 14.04 on another hard drive (/dev/sdb). 
I recently installed Ubuntu and it installed grub on my windows drive, and I would like to remove it. I installed grub onto my Ubuntu drive using `grub-install /dev/sdb` so now I have GRUB on both drives.

PS. The reason is that I almost never boot into Ubuntu (I access the installation from VirtualBox inside Windows) and when I boot into Ubuntu I prefer to select the boot drive (using F8/Esc) to select the Ubuntu disk and then load Ubuntu from the GRUB menu on the Ubuntu disk, as opposed to the GRUB menu every time I boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `bcdboot C:\Windows` as administrator in Windows 7 should reinstall the Windows bootloader in the MBR of the Windows disk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild the master boot record aka, MBR.  Follow the instructions here:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows

Also check this out, there is a free edition.

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there a way to do that without the installation DVD?

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please include instructions to solve the problem in your answer.

Comment: I don't believe you can rebuild the MBR without an install source.  Check this out though, there is a free edition.  http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential

wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ms-sys/ms-sys%20stable/2.4.0/ms-sys-2.4.0.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fms-sys.sourceforge.net%2F&ts=1415738967&use_mirror=ufpr

tar -xzvf ms-sys*.tgz
cd ms-sys
make
make install
ms-sys -7 /dev/sda
```

Note: This program is used to create Microsoft compatible boot records.

Usage:

```
ms-sys [options] [device]
```

Options:

```
-1, --fat12     Write a FAT12 floppy boot record to device
-2, --fat32nt   Write a FAT32 partition NT boot record to device
-3, --fat32     Write a FAT32 partition DOS boot record to device
-4, --fat32free Write a FAT32 partition FreeDOS boot record to device
-5, --fat16free Write a FAT16 partition FreeDOS boot record to device
-6, --fat16     Write a FAT16 partition DOS boot record to device
-n, --ntfs      Write a NTFS partition Windows 7 boot record to device
-l, --wipelabel Reset partition disk label in boot record
-p, --partition Write partition info (hidden sectors, heads and drive id)
                to boot record
-H, --heads  Manually set number of heads if partition info is written
-7, --mbr7      Write a Windows 7 MBR to device
-i, --mbrvista  Write a Windows Vista MBR to device
-m, --mbr       Write a Windows 2000/XP/2003 MBR to device
-9, --mbr95b    Write a Windows 95B/98/98SE/ME MBR to device
-d, --mbrdos    Write a DOS/Windows NT MBR to device
-s, --mbrsyslinux    Write a syslinux MBR to device
-t, --mbrgptsyslinux Write a syslinux GPT MBR to device
-z, --mbrzero   Write an empty (zeroed) MBR to device
-f, --force     Force writing of boot record
-h, --help      Display this help and exit
-v, --version   Show program version
-w, --write     Write automatically selected boot record to device

Default         Inspect current boot record
```

Warning: Writing the wrong kind of boot record to a device might
destroy partition information or file system!